# Instant messaging with kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, messaging, connector, instant, sink

I'm trying to design an instant messaging or more precisely I'm doing turn based game whose mechanism is the following:

Player "A" doing something and send information about his steps to player "B".
Player "B" receive this information also doing something and response back to player "A".

I'm thinking about kafka sink connector if it can be hosted outside of kafka just as a client? Because it's a good way to avoid to write a lot of code and to have a good mechanism of message receiver to client with partitioning, schemas e.t.c.
I want to do something as following, for instance:

Two clients can be subscribed to one topic and can exchange messages between each other with some information.

Is it possible something like that?

Or if it's not possible, I'm just thinking.. What, if to do 2 listeners one in the source connector and another one in the sink for sending and receiving messages in any way managed by kafka. Does it make sense, what do you think?

I'm just gathering ideas how to implement it best and fast as possible with good performance, scalability and less effort. :)

Comment: It sounds like you're gathering ideas for the design for your game engine. There are many, many ways this could be designed. I don't think SO is the right forum for this as it's meant for specific questions, not for brain-storming ideas, IMHO.